# Gunicorn not logging errors and print statements

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run a flask application using gunicorn, and logging it's errors and access to the files.
The access log is working fine, but the issue is arising in error log file.

The error log file manages to log the errors into the log file, but after a day or two it's not appending any more of the errors or print statement in the file.

Following is my gunicorn service configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 3 --capture-output --log-level debug --access-logfile /logs/access.log --error-logfile /logs/error.log --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app --reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am unable to track down the issue causing the same.
I deleting the file and it worked well for some time, before causing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python logging class and define app logger in app.py . also you need to set gunicorn logging logger in app.

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ != '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)

@app.route('/')
def default_route():
    """Default route"""
    app.logger.debug('this is a DEBUG message')
    app.logger.info('this is an INFO message')
    app.logger.warning('this is a WARNING message')
    app.logger.error('this is an ERROR message')
    app.logger.critical('this is a CRITICAL message')
    return jsonify('hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```